# Mysql select query performance gets bad

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select, union

I got a mysql query that selects all clicks for each hour of a day.
This query worked good till we have alot of click entries in our database. Now it needs sometimes several seconds (up to 9!) to request the datas...

The query is:

```
SELECT h.clickHour, COUNT(clicktime) AS c
      FROM ( SELECT 0 AS clickHour
             UNION ALL SELECT 1
             UNION ALL SELECT 2
             UNION ALL SELECT 3
             UNION ALL SELECT 4
             UNION ALL SELECT 5
             UNION ALL SELECT 6
             UNION ALL SELECT 7
             UNION ALL SELECT 8
             UNION ALL SELECT 9
             UNION ALL SELECT 10
             UNION ALL SELECT 11
             UNION ALL SELECT 12
             UNION ALL SELECT 13
             UNION ALL SELECT 14
             UNION ALL SELECT 15
             UNION ALL SELECT 16
             UNION ALL SELECT 17
             UNION ALL SELECT 18
             UNION ALL SELECT 19
             UNION ALL SELECT 20
             UNION ALL SELECT 21
             UNION ALL SELECT 22
             UNION ALL SELECT 23 ) AS h
    INNER JOIN links l ON l.user_id = 1
    LEFT OUTER
      JOIN clicks
        ON EXTRACT(HOUR FROM clicks.clicktime) = h.clickHour
          AND DATE(clicks.clicktime) = '2014-09-21'
          AND clicks.link_id = l.id
    GROUP
        BY h.clickHour
```

I got these unions because i need clicks for each hour also empty hours...
Please help!

Ok so we are talking about 0 to several thousand rows for the table clicks. The click time is saved as a timestamp and every click got a unique id. I see that the union thing is bad and i have to change it.

What i try now is to select all clicks of a day grouped by HOUR(clicktime):
But when i do so I get too many results like 10x then it should be.

Comment: Why don't you have all the clicks in one table with a column specifying the hour?

Comment: We need to know more. How many rows are we talking about? Have you used `EXPLAIN`? Do you have indices set up? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Ok so we are talking about 0 to several thousand rows. The click time is saved as a timestamp and every click got a unique id. I see that the union thing is bad and i have to change it. Excuse me but i dont know what EXPLAIN is?

Comment: @jab73: `EXPLAIN` gives us information about the query execution plan for a SELECT statement. Prefix your SELECT statement with the keyword EXPLAIN, and execute it, and you'll get back a result set with details about how MySQL is going to execute your query. Interpreting the output from EXPLAIN does require some understanding of what operations are available to the optimizer, and what influences the optimizer to choose a particular operation. Reference: [**8.8 Understanding the Query Execution Plan**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/execution-plan-information.html)

Comment: @jab73: the recommendations in my answer were based on a lot of assumptions about your tables, and some knowledge of how the MySQL optimizer works (especially in the ways it is limited, and can seem almost brain dead compared to optimizers in other RDBMS), but the limitations also make it fairly predictable, a lot more predictable than Oracle and SQL Server in some cases.) Tuning MySQL queries is a mix of science, history, art, and wizardry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd rewrite the query like this:

```
SELECT h.clickHour
     , IFNULL(d.clickCount,0) AS c
  FROM ( SELECT 0 AS clickHour UNION ALL SELECT  1 UNION ALL SELECT  2
           UNION ALL SELECT  3 UNION ALL SELECT  4 UNION ALL SELECT  5
           UNION ALL SELECT  6 UNION ALL SELECT  7 UNION ALL SELECT  8
           UNION ALL SELECT  9 UNION ALL SELECT 10 UNION ALL SELECT 11
           UNION ALL SELECT 12 UNION ALL SELECT 13 UNION ALL SELECT 14
           UNION ALL SELECT 15 UNION ALL SELECT 16 UNION ALL SELECT 17
           UNION ALL SELECT 18 UNION ALL SELECT 19 UNION ALL SELECT 20
           UNION ALL SELECT 21 UNION ALL SELECT 22 UNION ALL SELECT 23 
       ) h
  LEFT
  JOIN ( SELECT EXTRACT(HOUR FROM c.clicktime) AS clickHour
              , SUM(1) AS clickCount
           FROM clicks c
           JOIN links l
             ON l.user_id = 1
            AND l.id = c.link_id
          WHERE c.clicktime >= '2014-09-21'
            AND c.clicktime <  '2014-09-21' + INTERVAL 1 DAY 
          GROUP BY EXTRACT(HOUR FROM c.clicktime)
       ) d
    ON d.clickHour = h.clickHour
```

The approach here is to get the inline view query `d` to return a maximum of 24 rows. This cranks through the `clicks` table to get the counts. W're going to defer the join operation to the fixed set of 24 rows until after we have calculated the hourly counts. (The join to `h` is there only to get rows with zero counts returned, which would otherwise just be "missing" rows.)

You can test the performance of the inline view query `d`, and of the entire query, I suspect there won't be much difference. The cost of materializing the inline view `h` isn't that much (there's some overhead, but it's very likely that will use the Memory storage engine; it's small enough and it should be simple integer datatype.)  And that join operation of 24 rows to 24 rows won't be that expensive, even without any indexes available.

I suspect that the majority of time will be in materializing the derived table `d`.

We're going to want an index with a leading column of `clickDate`, so that we can use a more efficient index range scan operation, to avoid evaluating expressions for every flipping row in the table.

I changed this predicate: `DATE(clickTime) = '2014-09-21'` into a predicates that reference the bare column, this enables MySQL to consider an efficient range scan operation on the clickTime column, (to quickly eliminate a boatload of rows from consideration), rather than requiring that MySQL evaluate a function on every flipping row in the table.

Some performance gain may be obtained by making covering indexes available on the `clicks` and `links` tables (so that the query can be satisfied from the indexes, without a need to visit pages in the underlying table.)

At a minimum on the clicks table:

```
ON clicks (clickTime, link_id)
```

If `id` is unique (or primary key) on the `links` table, this index may not give any performance benefit:

```
ON links (id, user_id)
```

If a covering index used, the EXPLAIN output should show "Using index".

I don't see a way around the "Using filesort" operation, not without adding a column to `clicks` table that stores the clickTime truncated to the hour. With a column like that, and an appropriate index, it's possible that we could get the `GROUP BY` operation optimized using the index, avoiding the "Using filesort" operation.

Comment: Thanks alot this query made the change! Got now 0.0007 Seconds for the request instead of 9!

Answer (score 0):

Have you indexed?

Clicks table: clicktime, link_id

Links table: id, user_id

Comment: yes table links got the user_id and table clicks got the link_id

Comment: could you add more details like Sverri M. Olsen mention? How big the data we are talking about? What have u tried? How about the index for clicktime?

Comment: added more infos to the original post. What do you mean with index of clicktime? the id of the click table?

Comment: to increase the performance you need to index important column. Since the clicktime you used in where clause to differentiate a date record you might need to index it properly. EXPLAIN means the query syntax, it can help you identified which part can be improved(performance)

Comment: Yes, an index with a leading column of `clickTime` would be beneficial for some queries, but MySQL can't make use of a range scan operation on that index to satisfy the predicate on `DATE(clickTime)`; MySQL has to evaluate that expression (call the DATE function) on every flipping row in the table. If we rewrite that predicate to be on the "bare" column... `clickTime >= x AND clickTime < y`, then MySQL can make effective use of the index.

Comment: I see. I have suspected that one. But did mySQL can put 'DATE(clicks.clicktime)' into one index? Because I remember I have done it in Oracle with a function(column). Thanks for your information.

Comment: @matrono: oh, how we _long_ for Oracle-style function based indexes in MySQL. But, alas, no. No support in MySQL for function based indexes. The workaround in MySQL is to define a column in the table to store the result of the function/expression, to materialize that as an actual column, and then index that column. In the query, we ref that col. (There's the whole messy bit about that column not being "in sync" with the source columns...   and Oracle function-based indexes avoid that by automatically maintaining that, and not giving anyone the ability to muck with what's stored in the index.)